# How can I use 16mm 40kHz waterproof ultrasonic transducers to measure distance?

Tags: sensor, ultrasound, distance, transducer, waterproof

I have these 16mm 40kHz waterproof ultrasonic transducers：[Manorshi MSW-A1640H12TR](https://www.makerfabs.com/desfile/files/MSW-A1640H12TR.pdf).

I am wondering how to measure distance with these transducers. I desoldered the non-waterproof transducers from a US-100 ultrasonic module and soldered these transducers into that module and it didn't work. Does anyone know of a circuit or something else to get this thing working?

Comment: Have you got the specification of the transducers from the US-100 ultrasonic module?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't destroy the module by desoldering/soldering??

Comment: How do you know that they are compatible? They could be designed to operate at different frequencies, require different drive strengths, or have different sensitivities.

Comment: The datasheet of transducers used in the US-100 module says 120dB sound pressure level at 10 Vrms. I assume, that the waterproof version mentioned here is far away from this, since it allows 150 Vpp driving voltage. However, a sound pressure level is not mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use ultrasonic transducers to measure distance?

Two separate tasks:

1. Emit an ultrasonic "chirp" or "pulse."  This is a short burst of the fundamental frequency, which for this piezo device is 40.0kHz.  This pulse emits a uniform wave "front" which begins travelling from the device at the [speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) (343m/s.)
2. Immediately after emitting the chirp, switch over to "receive amplification" mode, where the piezo is used as a sensor.  As the 40kHz chirp is reflected off of objects, some small amount of that energy returns to the piezo and causes it to vibrate, creating a small voltage.  This is amplified for greater sensitivity (and longer detection range.)

The amount of time elapsed between the emission of the pulse and the detected return pulse, is the distance.  For instance, if it took 12ms for the pulse to return, then 0.012s * 343m/s = 4.116m.  But consider that this is round-trip distance; the linear distance is half of that, or about 2m.

Comment: Good technical description, but I believe that the OP wants a plug-and-play solution. Something with the electronics integrated and a serial interface to his MCU.

Comment: I wonder, since s/he mentioned "waterproof", if the application is underwater?

Comment: If underwater, the speed of sound in water is ~1500m/s (The World Book Encyclopedia. Chicago: World Book, 1999. 601.)